# FirefoxDriver Selenium does not work (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to set up a FirefoxDriver with Selenium in Java. I tried it as follows:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "proxy");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "1234");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

    driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

But it always gives me the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

After google this it turned out that this is common problem but I did not find any solution!
I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar and Firefox 29.0
Can anybody please help me?!

Comment: Your code looks fine.
I did not observed the problem you are getting.

Comment: selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar and Firefox 29.0.1 work well for me. I suggest you re-install Firefox with other version.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me even not if use an older FF version (27.0.1 was recommended) :(

Comment: I found out that this is working fine on another system. strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the proxy details manually in firefox browser and see if you are able to access